Applying homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions in 2D eigenvalue equation
I am solving the linear Schrödinger equation:
$$-\dfrac12h^2 ( u(i+1,j) + u(i-1,j) + u(i,j+1) + u(i,j-1) - 4*u(i,j) ) - R * u(i,j) = b * u(i,j).$$
Using finite discretization in real space we can write it as $A * u = b * u$.
It is an eigenvalue equation and it can easily be solved in MATLAB.
However when I construct the matrix $A$, I want to make sure that the boundary conditions are there, I think they are equal to zero at the boundaries.
What is the shape of the matrix $A$?
How boundary conditions affect its shape?

Can you use latex  to type your answer, thanks!

If the boundary conditions are $0$, you can just remove their equations from the system and set $u=0$ for all the boundary elements in the remaining equations. You will end up with an $N\times N$ system where $N$ is the number of interior nodes.
For example, the equation at the bottom left interior node of the domain will look like
$$
-\frac{1}{2h^2}(u_{2,1} +u_{1,2} - 4u_{11}) - Ru_{11} = bu_{11}.
$$
Similarly, the equation for a node adjacent to the bottom side (not a corner) will look like
$$
-\frac{1}{2h^2}(u_{i+1,1} + u_{i-1,1} + u_{i,2} - 4u_{i,1}) - Ru_{i,1} = b u_{i,1}.
$$
The exact indexing will depend on how you order the elements of the domain but this is the general principle.
